# Jquery plugin with continuous scroll like news ticket

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a customisable news ticker style jQuery plugin with:

- Continuous scroll
- Buttons left/right
- Pause on hover

I have found [liScroll](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html) which does exactly like I want but with no left/right buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found this site dedicated to similar functionality. It may not be what you're looking for, though... http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/.

Alternatively maybe this [BBC style news ticker](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/BBCnewsTicker)?? Just try searching through the jQuery plugins library and I'm sure you'll find something. Everything is documented well enough that you should pickup what you need to do as far as customizations.

Resource: http://plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: I am wanting more of a carousel than an actual news text.